# In minibuffer forward through search history M-p not work

Tags: minibuffer, isearch

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

Steps:

1. Start Emacs
2. Open `*scratch*` buffer.
3. `C-s` text
4. `C-g`
5. `C-s` visit
6. `C-g`

Nice. Now I want to go backward and forward through search history with `M-p` and `M-n` respectively.
But I get error:

```
M-p/M-n is underfined".
```

If I input command "`previous-history-element`" I get another error: `Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`

I try this in pure Emacs by: `emacs -Q`

But I get same errors.

Comment: Why are you typing `M-x C-s`? I've just checked Emacs 26.1 under windows 7 without any init file, and `isearch` history seems to just work for me.

Comment: Maybe this will help out a little bit: https://asciinema.org/a/nzAMu0WCJrV9vPVV4was69qZk

Comment: Because C-s is incremental search forward (isearch-forward)

Comment: You don't need to prefix it with `M-x`.

Comment: I update my post. It's not help. I get same error

Comment: I also try this on Linux Mint. But I get same result.

Answer (score 2):

When you cancel the search with `C-g` the search item isn't added to your search history. Try this instead:

1. Start Emacs
2. Open *scratch* buffer.
3. `C-s` text
4. ENTER
5. `C-s` visit
6. ENTER

Now you can access your search history:

1. `C-s`
2. `M-n` or `M-p`